# Push a span to bottom in Bootstrap media-list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a simple forum.

An example of posts can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sKPhx/6/

The second and third post are fine. The fist post, I would like the bottom span which say:

```
Class: Sysop - Member: 3 years ago
```

To be pushed to the bottom, along with the hr tag. Is this possible with my current design?

Comment: Not going to fix your issue but a UL can only have LI elements as its children, not DIV elements as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is new jsiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sKPhx/7/

Add this styles:

```
.media {
    position:relative;
}
.bottomaligned {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

But try to reconsider a bit of restyling to keep the html a bit easier to maintain.